# javascript get Json data with fetch

Tags: javascript, json

I'm pretty noob in js. What I want to do is to send a get request to my server and receive a json. I can do this by fetch however, it returns a promise which is not suitable for me since I need to pass the received json to another function. Is there any way to get rid of promise? if not any alternative solution? I searched a lot but found no proper solution.

here's my function:

```
function fetchAndConvertData(path) {
    return fetch(path).then(response =>
        response.json().then(data => ({
                data: data,
                status: response.status
            })
        ).then(async res => {
            return res.data
        }));
}
```

Comment: I guess what you want is `await`, here some helpful link https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-fetch-async-await/

Comment: `a promise is not suitable for me since I need to pass the received json to another function.` I don't see the problem. Whenever the result is ready, pass it to another function. `Is there any way to get rid of promise?` You have to learn how to deal with asynchronism and Promises, not get rid of them.

Comment: `fetch(path).then(r => r.json()).then(yourFunction);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply write :

```
async function fetchAndConvertData(path) {
    const response = await fetch(path);
    const data = await response.json();

    return { // This is a Promise because async functions always return a Promise
        data,
        status: response.status
    }
}

(async () => {
    const result = await fetchAndConvertData("some/path/here");
    console.log(result)
})();
```